# RenderPartial and UpdatePanel differences?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Are RenderPartial,RenderSection (MVC) have the same concept as UpdatePanel which is to do partial postback.

Comment: They are completely different things. You can not compare them...

Comment: RenderPartial has nothing to do with postbacks.

Comment: Thank you. So it means that renderpartial is only for loading and reloading???

Comment: render partial is rendering partial HTML codes :) Check [HERE](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/)

Comment: Does the Renderpartial functions as a callback ???